# Returning current class object without inherited properties

Tags: php, class

I have an autoloader, initializing alot of objects as a mini-framework is loaded. The objects are saved as static variables, but now I've run into a problem. I have a file which is instantiated in the autoloader, but used later kind of like an exception handler, taking care of special cases when called. The intention is that the methods within this class returns $this, the class object, but when doing so, the returned value is not an instance of the called object, but gets inherited into the class which calls it. Furthermore the called exception_handler is not only an instance of itself, but everything instanziated throughout the entire autoloader, inheriting $this as everything gets loaded. Confusing but I've built a small example:

```
class a {
    public $a_tmp = 'tmp';
}

class b extends a {
    public $b_tmp = 'tmp';

    public function getOnlyThisClass() {
        return $this;
    }
}

$b = new b();
$b->getOnlyThisClass();
```

This returns:

```
object(b)#1 (2) {
  ["b_tmp"]=>
  string(3) "tmp"
  ["a_tmp"]=>
  string(3) "tmp"
}
```

And I need it to return ONLY the called class when special methods are called. I know this can be fixed with a factory pattern, but would like to avoid it in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not make `$a_tmp` private ?

Comment: This is a small example of what's happening, making $a_tmp private would mean I should make everything in the entire framework private because of 1 class. Maybe I'm wrong but then factory pattern is more appealing. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the problem, if you do: new b() this will return a instance of b inheriting some methods and properties from a. But when you call getOnlyThisClass you want the instance of b without the inerithed methods and properties?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Reflection to get class object properties without inherited properties:

```
<?php

class a {
    public $a_tmp = 'tmp';
}

class b extends a {
    public $b_tmp = 'tmp';

    public function getOnlyThisClass() {
        $cl       = new stdClass();
        $refclass = new ReflectionClass($this);
        foreach ($refclass->getProperties() as $property)
        {
            $name = $property->name;
            if ($property->class == $refclass->name) {
                $cc = $property->name;
                $cl->$cc = $this->$name;
            }
        }
        return $cl;
    }
}
$b = new b();
var_dump($b->getOnlyThisClass());
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["b_tmp"]=> string(3) "tmp" }
```

You can create an stdClass and assign found properties there.. Finish this to match your needs.

Comment: Great example, but can't really see how this would work, the class b needs to return itself as an object, an instance of itself. In my application there are methods within $b which I need to access once it has been called and stored in a variable. Yours return a string, which I can validate agianst. Deeper down in my app I need this to validate against "$tmp instanceof b".

Comment: I thought you need it just to debug.. Sounds like impossible to separate the class from it's parent and still being himself..

Comment: I think you're right, singleton factory pattern is my solution to this. Thanks for your help!